# PostgreSQL create a view to populate a list of personal records (i.e by the smallest value of a column chronologically)

Tags: sql, postgresql

### The example schema

| id | user | race_distance | elapsed_time | start_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bolt | 200m | 2050 | 2006-01-01 |
| 2 | Bolt | 100m | 970 | 2007-01-01 |
| 3 | Bolt | 100m | 999 | 2008-01-01 |
| 4 | Bolt | 100m | 958 | 2008-08-08 |
| 5 | Powell | 100m | 969 | 2008-08-08 |
| 6 | Bolt | 100m | 960 | 2010-01-01 |

### The problem

I'd like to extract the info in this table into a view that can show a list of PBs per athlete per distance chronologically.

### The Result View

| id | user | race_distance | elapsed_time | start_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bolt | 200m | 2050 | 2006-01-01 |
| 2 | Bolt | 100m | 970 | 2007-01-01 |
| 4 | Bolt | 100m | 958 | 2008-08-08 |
| 5 | Powell | 100m | 969 | 2008-08-08 |

So

- #3 is not a PB (as it spent a time of 999 which is slower than 970 achieved before)
- #6 is not a PB either as at the time the PB was 958 on 2008-08-08.

But both #2 and #4 are PBs, as on 2007-01-01, the PB achieved at a time of 970. Then on 2008-08-08, the PB was broken to 958.

### What I have tried

Honestly no clue how to achieve it with SQL view.
With programming pseudo code, it looks like this

```
pbs = []
current_pb = null

foreach record.filter_by(user, race_distance).sort_by(start_date) do |activity|
  if current_pb == null
   pbs << activity
   current_pb = activity.elapsed_time
  else
    if activity.elapsed_time < current_pb
       pbs << activity
       current_pb = activity.elapsed_time
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use raw Postgres SQL here, you may use `DISTINCT ON`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (user, race_distance, start_date) *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY user, race_distance, start_date, elapsed_time;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a cumulative max:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(elapsed_time) over (partition by user, race_distance
                                     order by start_date
                                     rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                                    ) as prev_max_elapsed_time
       from t
      ) t
where prev_max_elapsed_time is null or
      elapsed_time < prev_max_elapsed_time;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the task is to select PO based on the following definition:

> A PO for an individual, at a given race_distance is defined a there
> being no lessor elapsed time for that distance on a prior date.

With this definition select no row satisfying the above EXISTS. (assuming table name: race) then  (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=60c732fc5b8b2c42f91e441c85a2c074))

```
select r1.* 
  from race r1 
 where not exists 
       (select null  
          from race r2
         where r2.start_date < r1.start_date
           and r2.elapsed_time < r1.elapsed_time
           and r2.user_name = r1.user_name
           and r2.race_distance = r1.race_distance
        ) 
  --order by id; 
  order by user_name
         , race_distance
         , start_date;
```